# iPhone/Android app letting users share login/logoff statuses like Skype

Tags: iphone, android, push, push-notification

I need to develop an iPhone/Android app in which users can share their friend's online/offline status in real time.

When a user launches the app, the app shows which user is online. If someone changes the status, the other users can know this change.

This is almost the same function of Skype online/offline notification.

How can I implement this functionality? (I think maybe I should use Apple Push Notification Server for the iPhone app.)

Does anyone know any tutorials, example/similar code, or any other useful references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Push Notifications are not a good ideea. They are not real-time. The best way of implementing the needed behaviour is to have a thread polling the server (and will also work with any mobile/non-mobile OS).

On the server you should have 2 services:
(1) one that retrieves your friend list initial statuses and stores it
(2) another (the one that you poll) that only returns the statuses that changed meantime

You can implement if-modified-since on the (2)nd service so that your information exchange could be kept at a minimum.

Hope it helped